# How can I create a running average of the last N items in a time series?

Tags: python, linked-list

My basic idea was to create a linked list, and as each new value comes in, add 1/N times the new value and subtract 1/N times the first value, then move the pointer to first along by one and free the memory that had been associated with first.

This won't ultimately be implemented in Python but just to get the process clear in my head, I tried to write it in Python, but my implementation is flawed.  Do I need a doubly linked list for this?  Is there an alternative approach (not linked-list based) that would be better?

Here's my attempt so far:

```
class Link:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.next = None
        self.value = val

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self,maxlength):
        self.current_link = None
        self.maxlength = maxlength
        self.sum = 0.
        self.average = None
        self.length = 0
        self._first_link = None
    def add_link(self,val):
        new_link = Link(val)
        new_link.next = self.current_link
        self.current_link = new_link
        if self._first_link is None:
            self._first_link = self.current_link
        self.sum += val
        if self.length < self.maxlength:
            self.length += 1
        else:
            self.sum -= self._first_link.value
            self._first_link = self._first_link.next # this line is flawed
        self.average = self.sum/self.length
    def get_first(self):
        return self._first_link.value

# Main
ll = LinkedList(5)
for ii in xrange(10):
    ll.add_link(ii)
    print ii,ll.get_first(),ll.average
```

The problem is that _first_link gets set to a value that doesn’t have a next.  That is, _first_link gets set to the first item that's added, but its next is None, so I don't see how to move it along by 1 as I want to.  This is what makes me wonder if a doubly linked list is needed.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? I often find that using exponential moving average for this sort of stuff works really well and is easy to implement in a simple and performant manner: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average

Comment: Also, if your values can vary greatly in magnitude, your approach could be susceptible to numerical issues since in floating-point math, `((A+B)-A)-B` is not necessarily zero.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that compensated summation or something could be helpful for numerical accuracy but I'm not worried about that (the dynamic range isn't huge).

The problem I'm trying to solve is simply that I want to calculate the average of, say, the last 1000 numbers from a time series that will have hundreds of billions of values in it, so I don't want to store all values in an array.  It's even simpler than an exponential moving average — it's just a flat moving average that I want.

Comment: My point is that exponential moving average is actually easier to implement than a sliding window, since it doesn't need to keep any past values around (except the most recent average).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest implementation is to use a [circular linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circular_Linked_list) (a.k.a. a *ring*):

```
class Link(object):
    def __init__(self, value=0.0):
        self.next = None
        self.value = value

class LinkedRing(object):
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.sum = 0.0
        self.length = length
        self.current = Link()

        # Initialize all the nodes:
        last = self.current
        for i in xrange(length-1):  # one link is already created
            last.next = Link()
            last = last.next
        last.next = self.current  # close the ring

    def add_val(self, val):
        self.sum -= current.value
        self.sum += val
        self.current.value = val
        self.current = self.current.next

    def average(self):
        return self.sum / self.length


# Test example:
rolling_sum = LinkedRing(5)
while True:
    x = float(raw_input())
    rolling_sum.add_val(x)
    print(">> Average: %f" % rolling_sum.average())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this using [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and the numerically stable math for maintaining running averages:

```
import collections

class AveragingBuffer(object):
    def __init__(self, maxlen):
        assert( maxlen>1)
        self.q=collections.deque(maxlen=maxlen)
        self.xbar=0.0
    def append(self, x):
        if len(self.q)==self.q.maxlen:
            # remove first item, update running average
            d=self.q.popleft()
            self.xbar=self.xbar+(self.xbar-d)/float(len(self.q))
        # append new item, update running average
        self.q.append(x)
        self.xbar=self.xbar+(x-self.xbar)/float(len(self.q))


if __name__=="__main__":
    import scipy
    ab=AveragingBuffer(10)
    for i in xrange(32):
        ab.append(scipy.rand())
        print ab.xbar, scipy.average(ab.q), len(ab.q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I thought of a solution that works in O[1] time.  I'm still curious if anyone has a linked-list-based solution, but this solution avoids the LL entirely:

```
class Recent:
    def __init__(self,maxlength):
        self.maxlength = maxlength
        self.length = 0
        self.values = [0 for ii in xrange(maxlength)]
        self.index = 0
        self.total = 0.
        self.average = 0.
    def add_val(self,val):
        last = self.values[self.index%self.maxlength]
        self.values[self.index%self.maxlength] = val
        self.total += val
        self.total -= last
        if self.length < self.maxlength:
            self.length += 1
        self.average = self.total / self.length
        self.index += 1
    def print_vals(self):
        print ""
        for ii in xrange(self.length):
            print ii,self.values[ii%self.maxlength]
        print "average:",self.average

# Example to show it works
rr = Recent(5)
for ii in xrange(3):
    rr.add_val(ii)
rr.print_vals()
for ii in xrange(13):
    rr.add_val(ii)
rr.print_vals()
```